# Python xarray - vectorized indexing

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, python-xarray

I'm trying to understand vectorized indexing in `xarray` by following this example from the [docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/doc-fix-dask/indexing.html#vectorized-indexing):

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
da = xr.DataArray(np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4)), dims=['x', 'y'],
                  coords={'x': [0, 1, 2], 'y': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

ind_x = xr.DataArray([0, 1], dims=['x'])
ind_y = xr.DataArray([0, 1], dims=['y'])
```

The output of the array `da` is as follows:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

So far so good. Now in the example there are shown two ways of indexing. Orthogonal (not interested in this case) and vectorized (what I want). For the vectorized indexing the following is shown:

```
In [37]: da[ind_x, ind_x]  # vectorized indexing
Out[37]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2)>
array([0, 5])
Coordinates:
    y        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * x        (x) int64 0 1
```

The result seems to be what I want, but this feels very strange to me. `ind_x` (which in theory refers to `dims=['x']`) is being passed twice but somehow is capable of indexing what appears to be both in the `x` and `y` dims. As far as I understand the `x` dim would be the rows and `y` dim would be the columns, is that correct? How come the same `ind_x` is capable of accessing both the rows and the cols?

This seems to be the concept I need for my problem, but can't understand how it works or how to extend it to more dimensions. I was expecting this result to be given by `da[ind_x, ind_y]` however that seems to yield the orthogonal indexing surprisingly enough.

Answer (score 2):

Having the example with `ind_x` being used twice is probably a little confusing: actually, the dimension of the indexer doesn't have to matter at all for the indexing behavior! Observe:

```py
ind_a = xr.DataArray([0, 1], dims=["a"]
da[ind_a, ind_a]
```

Gives:

```
<xarray.DataArray (a: 2)>
array([0, 5])
Coordinates:
    x        (a) int32 0 1
    y        (a) <U1 'a' 'b'
Dimensions without coordinates: a
```

The same goes for the orthogonal example:

```py
ind_a = xr.DataArray([0, 1], dims=["a"])
ind_b = xr.DataArray([0, 1], dims=["b"])
da[ind_a, ind_b]
```

Result:

```py
<xarray.DataArray (a: 2, b: 2)>
array([[0, 2],
       [4, 6]])
Coordinates:
    x        (a) int32 0 1
    y        (b) <U1 'a' 'c'
Dimensions without coordinates: a, b
```

The difference is purely in terms of "labeling", as in this case you end up with dimensions without coordinates.

### Fancy indexing

Generally stated, I personally do not find "fancy indexing" the most intuitive concept. I did find this example in NEP 21 pretty clarifying: https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0021-advanced-indexing.html

Specifically, this:

> Consider indexing a 2D array by two 1D integer arrays, e.g., `x[[0, 1], [0, 1]]`:
>
> - Outer indexing is equivalent to combining multiple integer indices with `itertools.product()`. The result in this case is another 2D
>   array with all combinations of indexed elements, e.g.,
>   `np.array([[x[0, 0], x[0, 1]], [x[1, 0], x[1, 1]]])`
> - Vectorized indexing is equivalent to combining multiple integer
>   indices with `zip()`. The result in this case is a 1D array containing
>   the diagonal elements, e.g., `np.array([x[0, 0], x[1, 1]])`.

### Back to xarray

```py
da[ind_x, ind_y]
```

Can also be written as:

```py
da.isel(x=ind_x, y=ind_y)
```

The dimensions are implicit in the order. However, xarray still attempts to broadcast (based on dimension labels), so `da[ind_y]` mismatches and results in an error. `da[ind_a]` and `da[ind_b]` both work.

### More dimensions

The `dims` you provide for the indexer are what determines the shape of the output, **not** the dimensions of the array you're indexing.

If you want to select single values along the dimensions (so we're `zip()`-ing through the indexes simultaneously), just make sure that your indexers share the dimension, here for a 3D array:

```py
da = xr.DataArray(
    data=np.arange(3 * 4 * 5).reshape(3, 4, 5),
    coords={
        "x": [1, 2, 3],
        "y": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        "z": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
        },
    dims=["x", "y", "z"],
)

ind_along_x = xr.DataArray([0, 1], dims=["new_index"])
ind_along_y = xr.DataArray([0, 2], dims=["new_index"])
ind_along_z = xr.DataArray([0, 3], dims=["new_index"])

da[ind_along_x, ind_along_y, ind_along_z]
```

Note that the values of the indexers do not have to the same -- that would be a pretty severe limitation, after all.

Result:

```py
<xarray.DataArray (new_index: 2)>
array([ 0, 33])
Coordinates:
    x        (new_index) int32 1 2
    y        (new_index) <U1 'a' 'c'
    z        (new_index) float64 1.0 4.0
Dimensions without coordinates: new_index
```

Comment: great answer, thank you. For some reason, I couldn't get bracket indexing (`da[...]`) to work. The `isel` variant, however, worked just fine. Also, I want to add that this also works the same way with `sel` (or `interp` for interpolation) for those needing to index by dimension values, rather than dimension indexes.

Comment: Maybe my version of xarray is just kind of old (0.9.6), but I don't get the same output as you from this. It's similar, but the "new_index" doesn't appear in the output dataset. Seems like it isn't doing the vectorised indexing?: <xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 2, z: 2)>
array([[[ 0,  3],
        [10, 13]],

       [[20, 23],
        [30, 33]]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 1 2
  * y        (y) <U1 'a' 'c'
  * z        (z) float64 1.0 4.0